# SSRS Matrix Bespoke Headers (Still from datasource!!)

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, grouping

I have to create a matrix in SSRS to detail the number uses leaving an organisation.

The columns will all represent spaces of time spanning 1 week and the rows will all represent departements in the organisation. The detail portion will be a count of people who have left that area in that week.

I have a leaving date field in the DB but nothing that flags the specific intevals I have been told to use. That means that as the matrix is, it counts each of users that have left a specific department however the date range columns is 1 day, not 1 week. Is there a way to force the column headers to respect the week intervals I want given that they are currently coming from the dataset and are not hard coded?

Comment: Is it possible to revert to a tablix, hard code the interval headers for the columns and then apple some sort of WHERE to the data on a column by column or cell by cell basis but still keep the department grouping?

Comment: Firstly try to manage your data in sql itself by using `Group By` with date and making each group as one week period. That way you can manage to get all data in your required format

Comment: @CoderofCode - How though can I do that given that the date intervals are arbitrary and are not stored directly nor as flags anywhere at all?

Comment: Can you post some random data of yours with table structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly try to manage your data in sql itself by using `Group By` with date and making each group as one week period. That way you can manage to get all data in your required format

I don't know what is your columns so I am just showing a way to get the week groups from table and get the count of the people

```
 SELECT  DATEPART(wk, datevaluecolumn)     weekno
    ,   SUM(peopleleavingcolumn)           totalvalue
 FROM        yourTable
 GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, datevalue)
```

Comment: I see what you are going for and that is very nice, thank you. Unfortunately The column header are to be pre-determined date ranges (all spanning 1 week) - 

28/07/2014 04/08/2014 11/08/2014 18/08/2014 etc

SO I need to evaluate the leaving date, compare that to my intervals and then increment the count in the relevant matrix cell. I hope that makes sense